# AngularJS view not updating after model change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm writing a web-based game that allows you to bid on cards and trade them with other players. For this application I'm using Node, Express, MongoDB and Angular.

The view shows the player avatars and names along with their connection status. This connection status is saved in the game model but also tracked real-time via socket.io websockets.

**When a player joins the game, the server sends a message to all clients. The client then checks if the message is meant for them by comparing the game id.**

```
socketService.on("playerConnection", function(data) {
    if (data.gameId === gameId) {
        handlePlayerConnection(data);
    }
});
```

**If the message is meant for our client, data is passed to function 'handlePlayerConnection'.**

```
function handlePlayerConnection(data) {
    if ($scope.game) {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.game.players.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.game.players[i].user.id === data.userId) {
                $scope.game.players[i].isConnected = data.connected;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the view, I simply bind the player avatar to 'isConnected', so it shows/hides when a player connects/disconnects.

Every now and then, the game model changes (obviously), and the server tells the clients (again, by socket) to refresh $scope.game.

**Code below shows how the $scope.game is refreshed.**

```
function getGame(gameId, callback) {
    gameService.getGame(gameId, function(err, data) {
        if (!err) {
            $scope.game = data; // Set game

            if (callback) callback(data);
        }
    });
}
```

At this point, the view is basically frozen. It completely stops responding to player connects and disconnects. Refreshing the browser or controller fixes the problem.

I've logged $scope.game.players to console, and it seems to contain the correct connection statuses. The view is simply not responding.
I have tried to implement $scope.$apply() in various ways and places but all that gives me is '**angular.js:13920 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress**'. Wrapping $scope.$apply() in $timeout() gets rid of aforementioned error, but does not solve the problem.

After spending hours trying to fix this, I might have a case of tunnelvision. Endless kudos to anyone who can help me.

EDIT: Just realised all socket data is handled through a $rootScope.apply(). **Full code:**

```
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8180/");
return {
    on: function(eventName, callback) {
        socket.on(eventName, function() {
            var args = arguments;
            $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                callback.apply(socket, args);
            });
        });
    },
    emit: function(eventName, data, callback) {
        socket.emit(eventName, data, function() {
            var args = arguments;
            $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                if (callback) {
                    callback.apply(socket, args);
                }
            });
        })
    },
    off: function(eventName) {
        socket.off(eventName);
    }
};
```

Now I'm even less sure what to do though..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed it...

I forgot I was using a directive as a 'player'. For lazy reasons, instead of creating an isolated scope and passing the player object, I assigned the player object to the scope in the following way:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        /*
            Decided not to use an isolated scope because the
            player directive needs access to the $rootScope.
            The solution below eliminates the need of said scope.
        */
        scope.player = scope.$eval(attrs.player);

    }
```

As you see there is even a comment explaining my idiotic decision.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$scope.$$phase) {
    $scope.game = data; // Set game

    if (callback) callback(data);
}
```

This will trigger a digest if one is not currently in progress. Otherwise, your code will get updated by the running digest.

Comment: Unfortunately this check renders my view completely empty. No data to be shown.

Comment: Try wrapping your $scope.game data in an object and set the result of the update to a field on he object, and have three UI listen to that field. Angular might be losing he reference when you change the object.

Comment: No problem, hope my answers were helpful.